# Dynamic regular expressions in MySQL based on the contents of a table

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Is it possible to do this in MySQL?

```
select * from keyword 
where keyword NOT REGEX concat('\b', concat_ws('\b|\b', (select distinct(keyword) from negative_keyword)), '\b') 
limit 3;
```

It currently gives this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEX concat_ws('|', (select distinct(keyword) from negative_keyword)) limit 3' at line 1

The `concat_ws` by itself gives this error:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

I have to match whole words, not just substrings or exact matches. For example, negative keyword 'cat' should match 'black cat', but not 'catatonic'.

Comment: The words `REGEX concat_ws` do not appear in that query. But all that aside, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Instead of `\b`, use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  x
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  negative_keywords nk
            WHERE  nk.keyword = x.keyword 
      );
```

Comment: But I have to use regular expressions to avoid whole words only, not just words that match a substring or an exact match. For example the negative keyword 'cat' should only filter for 'black cat', 'cat box', but not 'catatonic'.

Comment: Please add that to your question; it complicates things quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, I had to filter them in code (PHP).

```
# filter negative keywords
$negatives = NegativeKeyword::find()->select('keyword')->distinct('keyword')->column();
$negatives = array_map(function($v) { return '/\b'.preg_quote($v).'\b/';}, $negatives); # escape regular expression, search whole words only
$kw = array_filter($kw, function($v) use ($negatives) {
  foreach ($negatives as $n) {
    if (preg_match($n, $v['keyword'])) { // strpos($v['keyword'], $n) !== false)
      // echo "filtering $v[keyword]\n";
      return false; // match found, filter word, break early
    }
  }
  return true; // good to keep
});
```